# Probability of a vegetables being selected for sale

Tags: probability

Here's the question:

**The probability of vegetables being selected from farm A is $\dfrac{3}{4}$ while the probability of vegetables selected for sale from farm B is $\dfrac{7}{9}$. Find the probability that vegetables selected for sale are only from one farm.**

What I don't get is $\dfrac{3}{4}+\dfrac {7}{9} > 1$. Shouldn't the possibility of selecting any vegetable from either farm $< 1$ ?

Comment: You need to take into account the vegetables that were selected from farm A *and* B, read about the IEP  here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: The question that you are *really* asking is: if $p_1$ is the probability that vegetables from farm A are sold, and $p_2$ is the probability that vegetables from farm B are sold, then doesn't $(p_1 + p_2)$ have to sum to a number $\leq 1.$  Re Csch of x's comment, this presumption breaks down if it is possible that vegetables from both farms are sold.  For example, suppose that $p_1 = 1$ and $p_2 = 1.$  Then it is certain that both farms will sell vegetables, which is certainly *non-contradictory*.  Re solving the problem, I (also) think CSch of x's comment is right.

Answer (score 1):

Let
A= event that vegetable is selected from farm A
B =event that vegetable is selected from farm B
P(A)=3/4
P(B)=7/9

P( vegetable is selected from only farm)
=P(vegetable is selected from A and not from B ) +P( vegetable is selected from B and not from A )

=P( A ∩ B')+P(A'  ∩ B)

=P(A)*P(B') +P(A')*P(B)

=3/4*(1-7/9)+(1-3/4)*7/9

=3/4 * 2/9+1/4 * 7/9

=6/36+7/36

=13/36